# Nuxt 3 `addServerMiddleware` only works in development, not in production

Tags: typescript, proxy, nuxt.js, middleware, nuxtjs3

Since [`@nuxt/proxy`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module) is not yet ready for Nuxt 3, I stole the code and used my own module temporarily. Unfortunately, the proxy only seems to work when in development mode. As soon as I build and run the server, the proxy is disabled. Broken down to the bare minimum, the module is:

```
import { addServerMiddleware, defineNuxtModule } from "@nuxt/kit-edge";
import { createProxyMiddleware } from "http-proxy-middleware";

export default defineNuxtModule({
  setup(options, nuxt) {
    addServerMiddleware({
      handler: createProxyMiddleware(
        "/uploads",
        { target: "http://localhost:1337/" }
      ),
    });
  },
});
```

The relevant parts of my `nuxt.config.js` are:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  buildModules: ["~/modules/proxy"],
  [...]
});
```

I also tried moving it to `modules` instead:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ["~/modules/proxy"],
  [...]
});
```

During build, the module is clearly run, as `createProxyMiddleware` logs the proxy to the console:

```
> nuxi build

Nuxt CLI v3.0.0-27369360.33ebb01                                                                                                                                                                       14:00:06
ℹ [HPM] Proxy created: /uploads  -> http://localhost:1337/                                                                                                                                             14:00:08
ℹ Vite warmed up in 3517ms                                                                                                                                                                             14:00:13
ℹ Client built in 8150ms                                                                                                                                                                               14:00:17
ℹ Building server...                                                                                                                                                                                   14:00:17
✔ Server built in 1899ms                                                                                                                                                                               14:00:19
ℹ Nitro preset is server                                                                                                                                                                               14:00:19
ℹ Cleaning up .output                                                                                                                                                                                  14:00:19
start Generating public...                                                                                                                                                                             14:00:19
✔ Generated public .output/public                                                                                                                                                                      14:00:19
start Building server...                                                                                                                                                                               14:00:19
start Writing server bundle...                                                                                                                                                                         14:00:23
✔ Server built                                                                                                                                                                                         14:00:23
  ├─ .output/server/index.mjs (69.6 kB) (23.7 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/nitro/static.mjs (11.1 kB) (2.92 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/index.mjs (392 kB) (90.3 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/vue3.mjs (284 B) (200 B gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs (240 kB) (55.2 kB gzip)
  ├─ .output/server/chunks/app/render.mjs (23 kB) (6.41 kB gzip)
  └─ .output/server/chunks/app/client.manifest.mjs (11.4 kB) (1.43 kB gzip)
Σ Total size: 1.68 MB (460 kB gzip)
ℹ You can preview this build using nuxi preview
```

But when I run the server, the proxy is not active. Lacking documentation, I presumed `addServerMiddleware` would work the same way `addPLugin` from `@nuxt/kit` works. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) package recipe for [Next.js](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/recipes/servers.md#nextjs) I came up with solution:

Define server middleware `/server/middleware/proxy.ts`

```js
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';

const proxyMiddleware = createProxyMiddleware(
  "/uploads",
  { target: "http://localhost:1337/" }
);

export default (req, res) => {
  proxyMiddleware(req, res, (result: unknown) => {
    if (result instanceof Error) {
      throw result;
    }
  });
}
```

More about [Nuxt3 Server Routes](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/server-routes/)

---

**UPDATE**

Nuxt3 compatible proxy module
https://github.com/wobsoriano/nuxt-proxy